# AJAX Response on MYSQL duplicate entry

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have got my code working well entering information into a database then displaying it directly on a table but I wanted to add a message to show that there may be possible duplicates.

Below is my AJAX code which you can see on "success" adds the new row to the end. However this is broken if my PHP script returns a "duplicate found" message is it doesn't flow with the table scheme, so when I go to submit a new record the new one now doesn't appear at the end of the table.

I imagine it would have something to do with calling json_encode to send the error back and trigger a event but I can't find much reference on using it

Essentially what I want to do is run the message so it doesn't break the $(".global_table tr:nth-last-child(2)").after(response); part when I add another row. take a look at booking.everythingcreative.co.uk for a working example

```
$("#insert_record").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($("#insert_firstname").val()==='')
        {
            alert("Please enter firstname");
            return false;
        }
        if($("#insert_surname").val()==='')
        {
            alert("Please enter surname");
            return false;
        }
        if($("#insert_email").val()==='')
        {
            alert("Please enter email address");
            return false;
        }

        $("#insert_record").hide(); //hide submit button
        $(".global_loading").show(); //show loading image

        //var myData = 'content_txt='+ $("#contentText").val(); //build a post data structure
        var firstname = $("#insert_firstname").val(); //build a post data structure
        var surname = $("#insert_surname").val(); //build a post data structure
        var email = $("#insert_email").val(); //build a post data structure
        var dates = $("#insert_dates").val(); //build a post data structure
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "assets/scripts/ajax.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data: {firstname: firstname, surname: surname, email: email, dates: dates}, //Form variables
        success:function(response){
            $(".global_table tr:nth-last-child(2)").after(response);
            $("#insert_firstname").val(''); //empty text field on successful
            $("#insert_surname").val(''); //empty text field on successful
            $("#insert_email").val(''); //empty text field on successful
            $("#insert_record").show(); //show submit button
            $(".global_loading").hide(); //hide loading image

        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            $("#insert_record").show(); //show submit button
            $(".global_loading").hide(); //hide loading image
            alert(thrownError);
        }
        });
});
```

Here is my response code from my PHP script but it triggers as a "success" to the code above

```
<div id="global_duplicate_container">
<div id="global_duplicate">
<div class="header">Duplicate Entry</div>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" class="global_table">
  <tr>
    <td>Candidate Information</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $check_info["customer_firstname"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $check_info["customer_surname"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $check_info["customer_email"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo date('l dS F, Y', strtotime($training_info['training_datetime'])) ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="button_live" href="#">More Infomation</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="button_live close_window" href="#">Close</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

So far this is whats happening when the form is submitted:
- Using AJAX the script checks the database to see if the if the entry is a duplicate
- If it finds a duplicate the script needs to tell the user of a duplicate and stop the script

However currently the following happens:
- The ajax.php script sends back some HTML which the javascript classes as a success and the code as an extra row on the the bottom, however this then breaks when the script is run again as the  tags are now broken with a  tag.

What I need to happen is to tell the javascript that the form hasn't been a success and to run the div somewhere else on the page like this:

```
 if($duplicate == true) { 
//tell hidden message to appear with details from php script
} else { //run standard ajax success code
```

Heres my PHP:

```
//Check that fields have been filled *NEEDS UPDATING*
if(isset($_POST["firstname"]) && strlen($_POST["firstname"])>0) {

    //$contentToSave = filter_var($_POST["firstname"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); 
    $insert_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $insert_training = filter_var($_POST["dates"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); 
    $insert_firstname = filter_var($_POST["firstname"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); 
    $insert_surname = filter_var($_POST["surname"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); 
    $insert_email = filter_var($_POST["email"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

    //Check database for possible duplicate
    $database_check = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM booking_customer WHERE customer_firstname='$insert_firstname' AND customer_surname='$insert_surname' AND customer_email='$insert_email'");
    $check_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($database_check);
    $check_count = mysqli_num_rows($database_check);
    if($check_count >= 1) {

    // Connect to all training dates to attain training day
    $database_training = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM training_dates WHERE training_id='$insert_training'");
    $training_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($database_training);

        ?>
        <div id="global_duplicate_container">
<div id="global_duplicate">
<div class="header">Duplicate Entry</div>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" class="global_table">
  <tr>
    <td>Candidate Information</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $check_info["customer_firstname"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $check_info["customer_surname"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $check_info["customer_email"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo date('l dS F, Y', strtotime($training_info['training_datetime'])) ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="button_live" href="#">More Infomation</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="button_live close_window" href="#">Close</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<?php
        exit;

    } else {

    // Insert sanitize string in record
    $insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO booking_customer(customer_added_datetime, customer_added_by, customer_training_table, customer_firstname, customer_surname, customer_email) VALUES('$insert_datetime', '0','$insert_training','$insert_firstname','$insert_surname','$insert_email')");

    if($insert_row)
    {

    // Connect to all training dates to attain training day
    $database_training = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM training_dates WHERE training_id='$insert_training'");
    $training_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($database_training);

    // Connect to customer details
    $database_customer = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM booking_customer WHERE customer_firstname='$insert_firstname' AND customer_surname='$insert_surname' AND customer_email='$insert_email'");
    $customer_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($database_customer);

         //Record was successfully inserted, respond result back to index page
          $my_id = $mysqli->insert_id; //Get ID of last inserted row from MySQL
   //echo "</tr>";
   echo "<tr id=\"customer_".$customer_info['customer_id']."\">";
   echo "<td>".$insert_firstname."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$insert_surname."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$insert_email."</td>";
   echo "<td>".date('l dS F, Y', strtotime($training_info['training_datetime']))."</td>";
   echo "<td><a class=\"confirmation button_live\" href=\"tcpdf/PDF/testPDF.php?id=".$customer_info['customer_id']."&version=email\">Send Invitation</a></td>";
   echo "<td><a class=\"confirmation button_live\" href=\"tcpdf/PDF/testPDF.php?id=".$customer_info['customer_id']."&version=download\">Download</a></td>";
   echo "<td>???????</td>";
   echo "<td><a href=\"#\" id=\"delete_".$customer_info['customer_id']."\" class=\"button_delete\">Remove</a></td>";

          $mysqli->close(); //close db connection

    }else{

        //header('HTTP/1.1 500 '.mysql_error()); //display sql errors.. must not output sql errors in live mode.
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Looks like mysql error, could not insert record!');
        exit();
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: it's not totally clear what the objective is when a duplicate is found, or what you currently return when it is

Comment: Sorry what I want to do is run the message so it doesn't break the $(".global_table tr:nth-last-child(2)").after(response); part when I add another row. take a look at http://booking.everythingcreative.co.uk for a working example

Comment: should update question so it is clear to all and not just a comment

Comment: I've added the comment

Comment: Still not entirely clear exactly what needs to happen for duplicates. This should be spelled out more. WHat gets returned? what should happen in UI?

Comment: I've added more to the bottom but all i want to know is how to get ajax to check if the php script is finding a duplicate and if it as to let the ajax code run something other than "success" unless something else needs to be done inside "success"

Comment: Um - won't handling the error/success in php and handling the results always in ajax:success solve your issue? (As - `json_encode(array('error' => [insert_row]))`). I'd say - onerror is more of "I didn't receive any response".

Comment: can check the response first within success.... and use `if/else` depending on what is returned. I prefer always using json but can be done using html  `if( response ==="duplicate")` and send string `"duplicate"` back

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by using json_encode as suggested by eithedog using the following code

```
success:function(response){
                var outcome = $.parseJSON(response);
                if(outcome['duplicate'] == "true") {
                    $('#duplicate_firstname').html(outcome['firstname']);
                    $('#duplicate_surname').html(outcome['surname']);
                    $('#duplicate_email').html(outcome['email']);
                    $('#duplicate_training_date').html(outcome['training']);
                    $("#global_duplicate_container").fadeIn();
                } else {
                    var record =    '<tr id="customer_'+ outcome['id'] +'">\
                                    <td>'+ outcome['firstname'] +'</td>\
                                    <td>'+ outcome['surname'] +'</td>\
                                    <td>'+ outcome['email'] +'</td>\
                                    <td>'+ outcome['training'] +'</td>\
                                    <td><a class="confirmation button_live" href="tcpdf/PDF/testPDF.php?id='+ outcome['id'] +'&version=email">Send Invitation</a></td>\
                                    <td><a class="confirmation button_live" href="tcpdf/PDF/testPDF.php?id='+ outcome['id'] +'&version=download">Download</a></td>\
                                    <td>???????</td>\
                                    <td><a href="#" id="delete_'+ outcome['id'] +'" class="button_delete">Remove</a></td>';
                    $(".global_table tr:nth-last-child(2)").after(record);
                }
            },
```